# Incremental fetch from Oracle

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Is there any way to fetch incremental data from an Oracle database using user-defined query using JDBC?

We are ok to use Spark, Kafka or plain JDBC.

The only thing it should be able to support heavy load.

Comment: Your questions is too broad. Yes it can be done with JDBC if you design a table with some sort of `loaded_time` column.

Comment: You can use CDN(Continuous Query Notification) https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/odpnt/featChange.html#GUID-ED1976AF-BB1D-44C9-9790-00D8866E6873 . But this technology has some limitations. Then you could user Shareplex or GoldenGate to dig data from Oracle redologs and transfer them into Kafka streams. But these products are are licensed separately.

Comment: Most of SQL database recommends creating Primary Key for a table. Primary Keys are unique. I would recommend you to checkout sequence, primary key and select query.

Comment: Question is unclear. Please try to explain in detail i.e. What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not specified the destination. If it's a Kafka topic then using Apache Kafka makes sense to do the extract too, using Kafka Connect.

In which case, you can use the [Kafka Connect JDBC connector](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-jdbc/) to do this. See [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector#query-based-ingest)  for the specifics on using incremental mode with a custom query.

++ EDIT ++

If your final target is BigQuery then you can use Kafka Connect for that too with the appropriate [BigQuery connector](https://www.confluent.io/connector/bigquery-sink-connector/). You can see an example of it in action [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-wrangling-apache-kafka-ksql).

Comment: Yes it is kafka-topic -> python subscriber -> pubsub -> bigquery

Comment: I've updated my answer to include info about bigquery and Kafka Connect.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that out.